# Get contacts list in iOS8, crashes the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, contacts

Getting contacts in iOS8 (iPhone 5s) causes crash randomly.
Crash details: http://hastebin.com/ukihinucaf.md

At line:

```
    ABMultiValueRef multiEmails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
```

Here is the whole function:

```
-(NSArray *) getAllContacts
{

    CFErrorRef *error = nil;

    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);

    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
    if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) {
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            accessGranted = granted;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    }
    else {
        accessGranted = YES;
    }

    if (accessGranted) {

        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
        ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
        CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
        CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
        NSMutableArray* items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:nPeople];
        for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++)
        {

            ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

            //get Contact email

            ABMultiValueRef multiEmails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

            for (CFIndex j=0; j<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiEmails); j++) {
                CFStringRef contactEmailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiEmails, j);
                NSString *contactEmail = (__bridge NSString *)contactEmailRef;

                [items addObject:contactEmail];
            }

        }
        return items;

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Cannot fetch Contacts :( ");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fetch failed" message:@"Can't fetch your contacts." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        return nil;

    }
}
```

Anybody knows what can be a problem?

Comment: Could it be because of not being able to deal with the memory management properly. You are not releasing all the CF objects that you have created or copied and there seems to be many objects which are not being released. Is it likely that your app is killed due to memory warning rather than crash ?

Comment: Crash details: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0006000000000068 for ABRecordCopyValue method

Comment: Not that this is causing the issue but both `for` loops use the variable `i`. That's risky in general - avoid that.

Comment: You're also retrieving `ABAddressBookGetPersonCount` (the count of all the people in all of the sources), and using that as an index for just the people in the default source. There are other issues (as insane-36 pointed out, you're not releasing the memory; the way you're using error parameter of `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions` is never going to retrieve the error object if any, I wouldn't advise the semaphore model, etc.), but the potential mismatch of the index strikes me as the main issue.

Comment: Fixed indexes, but problem is still here.

Comment: Updated question with crash details: http://hastebin.com/ukihinucaf.md

Comment: As an aside, I'd suggest running this through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu). It's excellent for identifying all those situations where you may have neglected to follow the Create Rule (see [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029)). Bottom line whenever you see a function with `Create` or `Copy` in the name, that means that you're responsible for releasing it via `CFRelease` or `CFBridgingRelease`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are retrieving `ABAddressBookGetPersonCount` (the count of all the people in all of the sources, not just the count of people in the default source), and using that as the upper threshold when you're iterating through the array. But the array doesn't contain all of the people in the address book, but rather only those in the default source. Thus, you may exceed the number of items in the array.

I would suggest using `CFArrayGetCount` rather than `ABAddressBookGetPersonCount`.

Comment: You are right. I already fixed it using:
        NSArray *allPeoplearray = (__bridge NSArray*)allPeople;
        CFIndex nPeople = allPeoplearray.count;
But your way is more elegant :)

Comment: I just used the Core Foundation technique because your code sample was using Core Foundation to iterate through the array. But I actually prefer your approach is fine (though I'd use `__bridge_transfer`, or `CFBridgingRelease`, which will transfer ownership to ARC and release the array when it falls out of scope), and then retire the `CFArray` functions altogether. Same with the email address, e.g. `NSString *contactEmail = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiEmails, j));`.

Answer (score 2):

ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, **error**);

Should be this

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
```